# Protocol extension is working wrong

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols

There is protocol Reactiveable, which has method "reactiveViewModel()" that return view model

```
protocol Reactiveable {
    associatedtype R

    func reactiveViewModel() -> R?
}
```

There is protocol Bindable, which has property "viewModel" and associated type

```
protocol Bindable {
    associatedtype VM: ViewModel

    var viewModel: VM? { get set }
}
```

There is base view controller with generic type:

```
class ViewController<T: ViewModel>: UIViewController, Reactiveable {

    typealias R = T
}
```

There is child of base view controller:

```
class MainViewController: ViewController<MainViewModel>, Bindable {
    typealias VM = MainViewModel
    var viewModel: MainViewModel? = MainViewModel()
```

And i've wrote two extension for Reactiveable protocol. First implementation just returns nil, and second one return View Model, if Self: Bindable.

```
extension Reactiveable {
    func reactiveViewModel() -> R? {
        return nil
    }
}

extension Reactiveable where Self: Bindable {

    func reactiveViewModel() -> VM? {
        return self.viewModel
    }
}
```

But when i am running my app and open screen MainViewController, it's always calling first implementation and return nil. Why? In fact - MainViewController: Bindable!

Comment: Running the above code in Swift 5.2 results in the correct function call. Are you still experiencing this issue?